# Are .xyz domains usually blocked by mail servers?

Tags: domains, email, email-address

I have read answers on question [Email-prevalent domain, .xyz vs .email](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86601/email-prevalent-domain-xyz-vs-email) however that question is more than 5 years old and I would like to know if things have changed since.

Are `.xyz` domains usually blocked by mail servers and considered less reputable?<sup>[1]</sup> I would like to use `.xyz` domain for both web hosting and as my primary email address but I have some better options<sup>[2]</sup>.

---

<sub>[1]: I would be using reputable and paid email provider for handling my email but I'm worried other people might not receive my email due to some kind of filters. For example Apache's spam assassin [seems to block .xyz](https://github.com/apache/spamassassin/blob/trunk/rulesrc/sandbox/pds/20_ntld.cf) right away but not sure how prevalent this is.</sub>

<sub>[2]: I have an option to go with `.org` as well but since it's for personal use, it seems weird to be using this TLD.</sub>

Comment: That Spamassassin code DOES NOT block .xyz - it does say it is slightly (0.5 points - typically out if 5) more likely to be spam  - but unless there is very spammy content in the email - that is not going to make a noticeable difference difference to deliverability in Spamassassin.

Comment: Apologies that I voted against reopening the question - I feel the crux of your question - "Are .xyz domains usually blocked by mail servers and considered less reputable" remains a matter of opinion so off topic.  FWIW, I run Spamassassin, and I've assigned penalties of 1.5 to 2.5 to some TLD's.   On the other hand I see I've counterbalanced a particular .xyz domain I host to offset Spamassassin default penalties, for reasons including but not limited to the TLD....

Comment: Per http://archive.icann.org/en/tlds/  - .org domains can be registered **without restriction** (unlike .edu, .gov, and .mil for example).  Registering a .org for personal use is no weirder then registering a .com for this purpose (I have registered a .com for this purpose, and a good friend has the .org for his family name)

Answer (score 5):

> What I'm more concerned is if I'd get blocked by mail servers since .xyz was also used for lot of spam mail and what not.

You can not control what/how others configure their email systems.

Various systems are broken regarding new gTLDs, some even hard code the list of possible ones, and are not updated. Others can indeed apply some filtering based on some subjective rules.

> Is there a reason nowadays not to go with .xyz?

This is impossible to answer, even besides the fact it is a negative assertion. You may get problems with it, or maybe not, and you may get problems with others too, or not.

The only way to find out is to start using it, and then you will see how much it does work or not for your setup.

> The reason why I'm picking this one is because for other TLDs it's already taken

Are you sure? There are over 1500+ TLDs nowadays, is your string really registered everywhere?

> go with .org as well but since it's for personal use, it seems weird to be using this TLD

There is nothing weird about using a `.org` for an individual, and it is used so indeed.